# Remove occurance of backslash in string not followed by another backslash or pipe

Tags: regex, scala

Need help to create a regex that can work on backslash on the below conditions.

1> if the string contains  backslash ,not followed by another backslash or pipe consecutively  than I should return the string without backslash

2>if the string contains a backslash and a pipe consecutively than I should not remove the backslash.

3>if it contains  backslash followed by another backslash consecutively (`\\`) than I should not remove the backslash.

```
scala> val str = """Sports\s"""
str: String = Sports\s

scala> str.replaceAll("""\\""", "")
res70: String = Sportss

scala> val str = """Sports\\s"""
str: String = Sports\\s

scala> str.replaceAll("""\\""", "")
res71: String = Sportss

scala> val str = """Sports\\|s"""
str: String = Sports\\|s

scala> str.replaceAll("""\\""", "")
res74: String = Sports|s
```

In the above tests if the string contains a single backslash or combination of backslash and pipe , the backspace is being removed completely, What should I modify to handle the cases?

---

Based on my earlier question the working answer was provided, But here is another case where the solution is not working.

```
scala> val str = "Spo\\rts\\s"
str: String = Spo\rts\s

scala> str.replaceFirst("""^([^\\|]*)\\([^\\|]*)$""", "$1$2")
res102: String = Spo\rts\s
```

expected output should be without `\`

Comment: Try [`replaceFirst("""^([^\\|]*)\\([^\\|]*)$""", "$1$2")`](https://ideone.com/IscZJ0).

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, this is working. can you please explain the regex

Comment: @darmatter Why would you want to use some obscure regex to solve this problem? It would be much easier to express this directly in your programming language.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżewm, just updated the question.

Comment: That is not correct as per the requirements, there are 2 backslashes. *3>if it contains more than one backslash than I should not remove the backslash.*

Comment: @cbley any solution in scala apart from using regex?

Comment: My bad @WiktorStribiżew . I din't put my question properly earlier

Comment: Maybe you want [`.replaceAll("""\\(?![\\|])", "")`](https://regex101.com/r/2yic8g/1)? Please make your question clear. Do not use "EDIT:", just re-write it so that it could be understood and answered.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `.replaceAll("""\\(?![\\|])", "")` not working in case of `String = Sports\\s`. 
`scala> str.replaceAll("""\\(?![\\|])""", "")
res108: String = Sports\s`

Comment: So, you want to keep all occurrences of ``\|`` and ``\\`` and remove ``\`` everywhere else? Then use [`.replaceAll("""(\\[\\|])|\\""", "$1")`](https://regex101.com/r/2yic8g/2). But what about ``S\\\|t``? Probably you want [`"""(\\+[\\|])|\\"""`](https://regex101.com/r/2yic8g/3).

Comment: Sorry for the multiple edits @WiktorStribiżew.

Comment: this one is working ` """(\\+[\\|])|\\"""` . I wonder why did you removed the regex explanation

Comment: Because you did not need that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
s.replaceAll("""(\\+[\\|])|\\""", "$1")
```

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/2yic8g/3).

**Pattern details**

- `(\\+[\\|])` - Capturing group 1:

  - `\\+` - 1 or more `\` chars
  - `[\\|]` - a `\` or `|` char
- `|` - or
- `\\` - a backslash

The `$1` replacement pattern will insert the value inside capturing group #1.

See the [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/zrJ7ZQ):

```
val p = """(\\+[\\|])|\\"""
println("""Sports\s""".replaceAll(p, "$1"))  // => Sportss
println("""Sports\|s""".replaceAll(p, "$1")) // => Sports\|s
println("""Sports\\s""".replaceAll(p, "$1")) // => Sports\\s
println("""Sports|\\s""".replaceAll(p, "$1"))// => Sports|\\s
```